# convert date format M/d/yyyy to MM/dd/yyyy in c#

Tags: c#, telerik

I am trying to convert the date which is in format 4/3/1950 12:00:00 AM

I am getting the value of date from sql data reader

```
 string dob =Convert.ToString(MbrNameReader[2]);
```

the  output of **dob** string is **4/3/1950 12:00:00 AM**

Now I would like to convert this to **04/03/1950 12:00:00 AM**

I have searched google to get help and tried to do it this way which throws an error ParseExact has some invalid arguments

```
DateTime dob =Convert.ToDateTime(MbrNameReader[2]);
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dob, "MM/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

later changed it to:

```
string dob =Convert.ToString(MbrNameReader[2]);
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dob, "MM/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

which gives the below error:

```
Exception thrown executing coded step: '[VerifyAlerts_CodedStep4] : Verify the content of 'divs' with database contents'.
InnerException:
System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
   at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)
   at System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider provider, DateTimeStyles style)
   at Communicator.VerifyAlertContentsfirstFive.VerifyAlerts_CodedStep4() in c:\tfs\HASINC\Development\QAAutomation\Communicator\Alerts\VerifyAlertContents_firstFive.tstest.cs:line 190
```

can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong over here?

Comment: What is the Data type of column in SQL Database, If it is `DateTime`, then just get back the `DateTime` type object back and then format it. Presentation format has nothing to do how date is stored in `DateTime`, it is just for displaying/presentation purpose.

Comment: are you familiar with the .ToString("Format given here")

Comment: Yes MbrNameReader[2] is of type DateTime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `MbrNameReader[2]` is already a `DateTime`, you don't need to re-parse it. Just call [`.ToString` with the desired format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) after casting to a `DateTime`:

```
DateTime dob = (DateTime)MbrNameReader[2];
string formatted = dob.ToString(
    "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

To have a precise "format" you'd need it to be a string:

```
string s = string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}", dateTimeValue);
```

Comment: Just a minor change, `d` should be `dd`, double digit, as that is required format of OP.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at two separate issues:

1. System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact is throwing a format exception for one of the reasons [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. I believe you want your datetime format string to be:

   "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"